# Managing Time Periods in ink!

Tags: ink

I would like to create a contract (something like an ICO) with an opening and a closing time. The storage stuct looks like this:

```
    #[ink(storage)]
    #[derive(SpreadAllocate)]
    pub struct Postbox {
        **snip**
        open_time: ink_env::Environment::Timestamp,
        close_time: ink_env::Environment::Timestamp,
        **snip**
    }
```

and I get the

```
error[E0223]: ambiguous associated type
  --> lib.rs:14:20
   |
14 |         open_time: ink_env::Environment::Timestamp,
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: use fully-qualified syntax: `<Type as ink_env::Environment>::Timestamp`
```

error while building it.

**First question**:
How can I store a timestamp in the storage?

Also I would like to close the ICO in 1 week after opening.

**Second question**:
In Solidity I can use `block.timestamp() + 7 days` . Is there anything like that in ink?

Comment: does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52656814/can-i-alias-fully-qualified-syntax && https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have something like this..

```rs
pub struct PostBox {
    open_time: Timestamp,
    close_time: Timestamp,
}

impl PostBox {
    #[ink(constructor)]
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { 
            open_time: Self::env().block_timestamp(),
            close_time: Self::env().block_timestamp()
        }
    }

/// get open_time
#[ink(message)]
pub fn get_open_time(&self) -> Timestamp {
    self.open_time
}

/// get close_time
#[ink(message)]
pub fn get_close_time(&self) -> Timestamp {
    self.close_time
}

/// add 7 days to close_time
#[ink(message)]
pub fn add_seven_days(&mut self) -> Timestamp {
    // https://www.unixtimestamp.com
    // 7 days = 604800000 in Unix time
    let day = 86400000;
    let week = day * 7;
    self.close_time = self.close_time + week;
}
```